# Are parts of the Sphinx older than 5000 years?

Tags: ancient-egypt, architecture, archaeology

Are parts of the Great Sphinx of Giza more than 5000 years old? There was a controversy about this question 15 years ago on which I didn't find anything to conclusively prove or debunk it.

Comment: Is suppose you are talking about the Great Sphinx of Giza?

Comment: Yes, the Great Sphinx of Giza

Comment: Please add a link to the controversy you've referred to in your question.

Comment: This question is better suited to http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I'm sure the materials are older than the Sphinx, but what parts are you referring to?  There are always controversies about certain landmarks but unless you can specify the controversy this might be closed or moved to Skeptics.

Comment: Research on this topic tends to be hard...the ancient aliens pseudo cult loves this one (annubis statue pre-dating Egyptian culture).  Articles attempting to state it pre-date Eygptian culture tend to be prolific on sites like 'ancientaenda' or 'beyondtopsecret' and they drown out more serious research on the topic.  Easy to tell a good section of the population really really wants this to be true at any rate.

Answer (score 2):

This controversy is analyzed in detail under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_water_erosion_hypothesis

Comment: therefore this question can be closed unless there are new facts to be added which seems unlikely.

Comment: FYI, you can expand the link into an answer and _accept_ it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Orion correlation theory**

This is most likely connected to the Orion correlation fringe theory put forward by Robert Bauval.

[Orion correlation theory, History, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_correlation_theory#History)

> The Orion correlation theory was put forward by Robert Bauval

[Photograph of Robert Bauval on the right, by Filipov Ivo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bauval#/media/File:Shoh_Boval_Belintash_2014.jpg)
[image: Robert Bauval (right) and Robert Schoch at the prehistoric cult centre of Belintash (Bulgaria) in 2014.]

**10,500 BC**

The theory, as written in "the Mars mystery" posits that the original sphynx was first constructed to align perfectly with the constellation of Leo, 10,500 BC.

[Citation 8 to 10, History, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_correlation_theory#History)

> Their initial ideas regarding the alignment of the Giza pyramids with Orion: "…the three pyramids were a terrestrial map of the three stars of Orion's belt"[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZGDg.jpg) are later joined with speculation about the age of the Great Sphinx.[9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Sphinx_of_Giza#/media/File:Great_Sphinx_of_Giza_May_2015.JPG) According to these works, the Great Sphinx was constructed c. 10,500 BC (Upper Paleolithic), and its lion-shape is maintained to be a definitive reference to the constellation of Leo.

[Link for photo](https://www.google.com/search?q=mars%20mystery&sxsrf=ALeKk02kqBRq8RDsMcYaI-0doL4AZNBvfg:1614251832614&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=YIsqkPfSxJN4WM%252CEXiQElDllW9F4M%252C%252Fm%252F04t03qc&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQb2cF8wuZJW4EmdJNwTWZu_iTEyg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ9r3Y9ITvAhXCVRUIHaO1AwkQ_B16BAggEAI&biw=1366&bih=568#imgrc=YIsqkPfSxJN4WM)
[image: The mars mystery]

**Pseudoarchaeology**

The fringe theory has not gained wider acceptance from the wider Scientific or Archaeological community and has been labelled as a pseudo belief by Ed Krupp of Griffith Observatory in Los Angeles and Tony Fairall of the University of Cape Town,

[Critique, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_correlation_theory#Critique)

> Arguments made by Hancock, Bauval, Anthony West and others concerning the significance of the proposed correlations have been described as a form of pseudoarchaeology.[12]

> Among these are critiques from two astronomers, Ed Krupp of Griffith Observatory in Los Angeles and Tony Fairall of the University of Cape Town,

**Britannica encyclopedia**

According to the Britannica encyclopedia the Great sphinx is estimated to have been built somewhere between 2575 and 2465 BC.

[Great sphinx, Britannica encyclopedia](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Great-Sphinx)

> Great Sphinx of Giza, colossal limestone statue of a recumbent sphinx located in Giza, Egypt, that likely dates from the reign of King Khafre (c. 2575–c. 2465 BCE) and depicts his face.

[Photo by MusikAnimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Sphinx_of_Giza#/media/File:Great_Sphinx_of_Giza_May_2015.JPG)
[image: The Great Sphinx of Giza in May 2015]

**Are parts of the Sphinx older than 5000 years?** According to most reputable sources the Sphinx is thought to have been built approximately 4500 years ago, and anything else is unproven speculation.